# Grub font size very tiny and how to change

Tags: grub2, fonts

The relevant system configuration for this post is as follows:

-Computer-
Processor       : 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Memory      : 16109MB (2394MB used)

Machine Type        : Laptop

Operating System        : Ubuntu 20.10 groovey gorilla

User Name       : xxxxxxx

-Display-
Resolution      : 1920x1080 pixels HP Elite HDMI E233 monitor

OpenGL Renderer     : Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation

**Problem:  In this dual boot with W10 the GRUB boot
screen displays microscopically small fonted boot options.**

I have researched the most common fix involving editing
/etc/default/grub at: the GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 line however this was unsuccessful in the attempt. It messed up the fonts in the GNOME environment after that.

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

**Another fix I tried was booting into the command prompt on GRUBs loading and
try to find the available resolution(s) for the display by
running both
vbeinfo and videoinf**

The two were unsuccessful.  However videoinf returned a message that read

> **"videoinfo not allowed on DELL UEFI"**

So, now I have a situation where I do not know how to resolve the tiny font issue apparently
fixable by tweaking the DELL UEFI boot configuration.

**The Dell Boot configuration is as follows:
Boot Mode UEFI mode only
Secure Boot Mode Enabled**

I still need to get to the bottom of this but now it seems there is an issue with the
DELL boot setup I do not know anything at all about.

Also of note is that there is no Legacy support for this laptop.

Please inform me of any ideas I have not yet tried or provide some link(s) to
this issue.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a small screen with large resolution. Grub menu and all other grub stuff was displayed very tiny. In the grub command line I ran `videoinfo` and it displayed video resolutions. I changed the resolution accordingly in `/etc/default/grub`. Then ran `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. It worked and changed the resolution of grub. I got this from here https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-menu-font-size#adjusting-grub-resolutionn